# Jquery mobile Listview refresh works, but too late

Tags: listview, cordova, refresh

I'm creating a mobile app via phonegap (one html-page with 4 data-role-pages). On of the pages shows a listview.

On pagebeforeshow I dynamically add listitems to my ul.
On pageshow I do a refresh of the listview.

That works. However, the first one or two seconds I still see the list without the jquery mobile style. Only after that it refreshes to the correct style.

What could be the issue? 
(Remark: When I put the script tags in the head, then it works, but then other events don't work anymore. Not sure if this has got anything to do with it.)

Thank you,
Christophe

```
$("#tips").on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
    db.transaction(getDbTips, onDbError, onDbSuccess);      
});

$("#tips").on('pageshow', function(){
    $("#tipsLijst").listview('refresh');
});

function getDbTips(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TIPS (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, beschrijving)");
    tx.executeSql("SELECT * from TIPS", [], onSelectTipsSuccess, onDbError);
}

function onSelectTipsSuccess(tx, results) {
    $('.tip_item').remove();
    var len = results.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    $("#tipsLijst").append("<li class='tip_item'><a href='#detailsTip' onclick='sessionStorage.TipId=" + results.rows.item(i).id + "'>" + results.rows.item(i).beschrijving + "</a></li>");     
}
```

};

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="tips">
<div data-role="header">
   <h1>Kado-tips</h1>
   <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="tipsLijst">
    </ul>
</div> <!-- einde content -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Place it all inside the "pageshow".

```
$("#tips").on('pageshow', function(){
    db.transaction(getDbTips, onDbError, onDbSuccess);
    $("#tipsLijst").listview('refresh');
});
```

By UI design standards you dont want to make the user wait to see the UI, you want to make them wait to see data, if you need to make them wait at all. Also, the delay between pagebeforeshow and pageshow might be what is causing your issue.

Edit:

Try adding the refresh command after your append command in the same function.

```
function onSelectTipsSuccess(tx, results) {
    $('.tip_item').remove();
    var len = results.rows.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        $("#tipsLijst").append("<li class='tip_item'><a href='#detailsTip' onclick='sessionStorage.TipId=" + results.rows.item(i).id + "'>" + results.rows.item(i).beschrijving + "</a></li>");
    }
    $("#tipsLijst").listview('refresh');
}
```

Also, your for loop inside of the onSelectTipsSuccess function is missing its closing }. Hopefully that is just a typo here.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I already tried that. When I put them both in pageshow, the list first has no style, then the jquery mobile style and then returns to no style. All within 1 or two seconds.

Comment: Ahhh... I see updating answer with new idea. One sec.

Comment: Dom, this works. I already tried that last week, but I must have done something wrong then, because it works now! Thank you very much, you can take the rest of the day off :-) (unfortunately i don't seem to have the right to say your answer was useful...)

Comment: Glad I could help. I think new users need to wait an hour or so before they can mark an answer as correct or something like that.